# package androidx.appcompat.widget does not exist Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imageview, androidx

I have created a custom Class which extends ImageView. It was working perfectly fine until AndroidX shows up.

Here, the java code

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;


public class CloseView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public CloseView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
...
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Android shows 2 errors for this file

1. error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatImageView
2. error: package androidx.appcompat.widget does not exist

Has anyone able to fix this issue?

Comment: You are using support libraries but trying to import AndroidX packages. Use either of those not both.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should completely migrate to AndroidX to use its classes

1. Enable `AndroidX` in Gradle settings:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2. Replace dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

instead of

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Edit:

AndroidX is the newest replacement to all the previous numbered support libraries. Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) before you start using it.

Comment: Enable AndroidX in Gradle settings. Make sure to put it in gradle.properties